# how can i use short link to DATASOURCE folder

Tags: imacros

How can i shorter the directory code, cause i'm making requested script, and person that will use this, have another directory name.

SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Viktor\Documents\iMacros\DataSources\FacebookInviter\FBGroups.csv

Comment: Why not to use the default folder and therefore: `SET !DATASOURCE FBGroups.csv` ?

Comment: i'm  this method, but i have a lot of files in default folder.

Comment: is the set datasource function only available in the imacros enterprise edition? @Shugar

Comment: @marriedjane875, the `!DATASOURCE` variable is available anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
SET !DATASOURCE {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}\FacebookInviter\tv-series.csv
```

or set any folder variable you'd like.

Comment: Great! Works. Thank You. Maybe also you can help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922704/how-to-correctly-use-loop