# SAVEAS variable folder location [iMacros]

Tags: csv, variables, location, directory, imacros

So, I'm currently working on an iMacros script, and came to this error.
When doing a:

> FILEDELETE NAME=

or

> SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=

we can specify a folder, howevery how can we specify the folder with variables?
I mean like %USERPROFILE% since not everybody's username is Admin/Administrator etc. ... 
Because this is what i would love to do(which is not working):

```
'deleting previous temporary files
FILEDELETE NAME=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\temp.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
'extracting Txt
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'and saving them to the datasources location
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\ FILE=temp.csv
'and later calling the file
SET !DATASOURCE temp.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
PROMPT {{!COL1}}
```

Why I'm doing this is simply because some browser "track" automatation and disable some features than, however via this way(tested with C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\    ...) the browser is not "tracking". And yes I'm all the time in private browsing.

Comment: Do u use JS scripting?

Comment: As you can see, nope, only iMacros

Comment: Do you know about the [`!FOLDER_DATASOURCE` variable](http://wiki.imacros.net/!FOLDER_DATASOURCE)? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921157/how-can-i-use-short-link-to-datasource-folder) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET !DATASOURCE profiles.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
'deleting previous temporary files
FILEDELETE NAME=%{{USERPROFILE}}%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\temp.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
'extracting Txt
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'and saving them to the datasources location
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\ FILE=temp.csv
'and later calling the file
SET !DATASOURCE temp.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
PROMPT {{!COL1}}
```

Try this. Store the userprofiles in the profiles.csv

Comment: What I'm looking for is that the iMacros script should work on every pc, and i can't impossibly store every profiles in a profiles.csv ...
It really needs to be something like in batch where you can "call" this directory and add the rest at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a solution yet, the answers above are "unfortunately" not the solutions too...
What i did was creating a .jar programm, which changes by launching and pressing a button the first line to SET !VAR8 C:\User...
Later i used !VAR8 for the rest